# Defining spatial reference for multiple raster files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

How do I define the spatial reference for a bunch of `*.JP2` files?

```python
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Ortho"
lrs = arcpy.ListRasters("*","JP2")

for rs in lrs:
    print 'Raster = ' + str(rs)
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(rs,"C:/spatial_reference.prj")
```

If I then check the properties of the datasets, there is still no spatial reference define. Do I have to write/save it some how?

[image: raster dataset properties]

*If I set the spatial reference via the `Edit...` button (see screenshot) it works fine.*

---

## EDIT

**Just realized the script works fine!** *It may has some problems if the files are already open in a different session.*

Comment: It seems like that should work as is. The projection file is Ok? When using the edit button, you point to the same prj file and get a good result?

Comment: If your spatial reference is a standard coordinate system then why not create a spatial reference _object_ and use that, just like the first example in the Code Sample section of the help file for this tool?

Comment: Guys, you're right. It works. Just fore the files I had already open it didn't. Thx anyway!